# The /var/lib/pgsql directory has wrong permissions

Tags: postgresql, centos7

on centos 7,
installing Request Tracker

trying to do postgresql-setup initdb

keep getting:
The /var/lib/pgsql directory has wrong permissions.

i've chowned the folder recursively to the postgres user, and given it all 700 perms. i've verified the permissions and ownership with ls.

i've go no idea what is broken here, or how to fix.

Comment: Please quote the exact error message and show `ls -ld / /var /var/lib /var/lib/pgsql`.

Answer (score 9):

fixed by running with sudo. apparently needs root perms to do it